# Different ways to get balls from a box

Tags: algorithm

You have a box with of balls  ,We pull all balls from the box
But we can pull one at a time or three at a time
And the order of extraction matters.
The question is how many different ways are there to pull the balls out?
So if the:
Box contains 1 ball there is only 1 way.
Box contains 2 ball there is only 1 way.
Box contains 3 ball there is 2 way (pull 1 by one or three at once)
Box Contains 4 balls there are 3 ways:
1111
13
31

And the given was that for 7 balls there at 9 different ways to extract the balls from the box

So the question is given the amount of balls in the box,

The solution I came up with was recursive:

```
Int calculate(int balls){
   If(balls=0) return 0;
   If(balls=1) return 1;
   If(balls=2) return 1;
   If(balls=3) return 2;
    If(balls=4) return 3;

 return calculate(balls-1) + calculate(balls-3);
}
```

Is this correct?
Is there a way without using recursion?

Thank you

Comment: @user648026 recursion is correct. You can look into DP solution for this.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000930 includes a whole variety of ways to calculate this.

Comment: The answer for 0 balls is not clear; a more natural answer  to me would be 1, and then you can start using the recursive formula already when balls=3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is correct. However, there are ways to improve the performance of the algorithm using a technique called dynamic programming. In this case, you can memoize the results, which means storing all the intermediate results in a lookup table after calculating each of them once using recursion. This allows a solution that normally requires exponential time to complete in linear time. Here's an example implementation of that in JavaScript:

```js
function calculate (balls, map = []) {
  if (balls in map) {
    return map[balls]
  }

  switch (balls) {
  case 0:
    return 0
  case 1:
    return 1
  case 2:
    return 1
  case 3:
    return 2
  default:
    return map[balls] = calculate(balls - 1, map) + calculate(balls - 3, map)
  }
}

console.time('dynamic')
console.log(calculate(50))
console.timeEnd('dynamic')
```

Compare that to the naive algorithm:

```js
function calculate (balls) {
  switch (balls) {
  case 0:
    return 0
  case 1:
    return 1
  case 2:
    return 1
  case 3:
    return 2
  default:
    return calculate(balls - 1) + calculate(balls - 3)
  }
}

console.time('naive')
console.log(calculate(50))
console.timeEnd('naive')
```

Comment: `map[balls] !== undefined` instead of `balls in map`. Because `balls in map` looks like O(n) in itself.

Comment: @vivek_23 it's not. Checking property existence on any object is O(1) average, and specifically on an array is O(1) constant.

Comment: thanks for the info. So, JS might be doing the undefined check under the hood, to make it O(1)?

Comment: @vivek_23 `map[balls] = undefined; (balls in map) === true` so no. It's not the same check.

Comment: No, I mean how does JS compute the expression `balls in map`?

Comment: @vivek_23 it's like `map.hasOwnProperty('balls')` except it checks the entire `prototype` chain instead of just own properties, and it's more optimized than implementing it using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. I will explore that.

Comment: The problem with this solution (and my solution) is that it will lead to stackoverflow or out of memory when number of balls is high

Comment: @user648026 any input that would cause a stack overflow would be well outside the range of even a `double`. Is this a hypothetical concern or can you actually demonstrate this issue with a particular implementation that _wouldn't_ return a value of `Infinity`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need memoization (at least not for all values) or solving the recursion to write a non-recursive program for this - or similar cases.

Something like the following will do:

```
function calculate (balls) {
   if (balls=0) return 0; /* Or remove this line */
   if (balls<3) return 1;
   resMinus3=1;  /* The result for i-3 */
   resMinus2=1;  /* For i-2 */
   resMinus1=1;  /* And for i-1 */
   for(i=3;;++i) {
      newRes=resMinus1+resMinus3; /* The recursion formula */
      if (i>=balls) return newRes;
      resMinus3=resMinus2; /* Shifting results */
      resMinus2=resMinus1;
      resMinus1=newRes;
   }
}
```

The reason is that to compute the value for balls you only need values for balls-1 and balls-3, so you only need to keep track of three previous results to update the new one. Alternatively you could write this as a matrix update:

```
[resMinus1;resMinus2;resMinus3] <-[0,1,0;0,0,1;1,0,1]*[resMinus1;resMinus2;resMinus3]
```

Comment: If you used matrix exponentiation, you could do it in O(log n) matrix multiplies.

Comment: @rice Good catch; and since the matrix only contain non-negative integers it should be numerically accurate. Using eigenvalue decomposition one could get a formula close to floor(1.46^(I-2)*1.31+0.5) that computes it in O(1); but it is more complicated to get the constants right - and it may fail for some small values.

Comment: In fact, there is a closed form, which I found in OEIS/A000930. "a(n) = floor(d*c^n + 1/2) where c is the real root of x^3-x^2-1 and d is the real root of 31*x^3-31*x^2+9*x-1 (c = 1.465571... = A092526 and d = 0.611491991950812...)."

Answer (score 1):

From a [link in the comments](https://oeis.org/A000930), you can find this equation:

> a(n) = Sum_{i=0..floor(n/3)} binomial(n-2*i, i)

```js
function binom(n, k) {
  var coeff = 1;
  for (var i = n-k+1; i <= n; i++) coeff *= i;
  for (var i = 1;     i <= k; i++) coeff /= i;
  return coeff;
}
function calculate (balls) {
  sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= Math.floor(balls/3); i++){
      sum += binom(balls - 2*i, i);
  }
  return sum;
  
}
console.time('someMathGenius')
console.log(calculate(50))
console.timeEnd('someMathGenius')
```

Comment: "a(n) = floor(d*c^n + 1/2) where c is the real root of x^3-x^2-1 and d is the real root of 31*x^3-31*x^2+9*x-1 (c = 1.465571... = A092526 and d = 0.611491991950812...)." (Bertrand Cloitre, found in OEIS/A0000930)

Comment: I saw that after. Editing now!

Comment: @rici was that determined empirically or was that derived somehow?

Comment: @patrick: i don't know how M. Cloitre figured it out, but it can be proven.

Comment: @rici so it's an exact formula, not an approximation?

Comment: @patrick: if his proof is correct :-). There are similar closed form solutions for fibonacci numbers and other similar sequences.

Answer (score 1):

For N balls, you can pull between 0 and floor(n/3) triples.

For N balls where you pull k triples, you also pull  N-3k singles.

Now the problem is reduced to counting the distinct ways you can order k things of one type, and N-3k things of another type. This is choose(k + N-3k, k) = choose(N-2k,k).

Final answer is the sum from k=0 to floor(N/3) of choose(N-2k,k).

```
N=0: choose(0,0) = 1 so there is 1 way of choosing nothing.
N=1: choose(1,0) = 1
N=2: choose(2,0) = 1
N=3: choose(3,0) + choose(1,1) = 1+1 = 2
N=4: choose(4,0) + choose(2,1) = 1+2 = 3
...
N=7: choose(7,0) + choose(5,1) + choose(3,2) = 1 + 5 + 3 = 9
```